# qsort is not really sorting

Tags: esp8266

I'm working with Arduino and getting some strange errors. qsorting is not sorting correctly.

```
//using this libraries
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

//the red struct is

typedef struct {
    int32_t rssi;
    int id;
} red;

//Here is my compare function
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  yield();
  red *redA = (red *)a;
  red *redB = (red *)b;
  //Serial.printf("redA->rssi: %d, redB->rssi: %d\n",redA->rssi,redB->rssi);
  //Serial.flush();

  return redA->rssi > redB->rssi ? 1 : (redB->rssi < redA->rssi ? -1 : 0);
  //return ( redB->rssi - redA->rssi );
}


void showNetworks(){
  int n = WiFi.scanNetworks(false,false);
  red listOfRedes[n];


  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // ...initialize it
  { 
    yield();
    listOfRedes[i].rssi = WiFi.RSSI(i);
    listOfRedes[i].id = i; 
    Serial.printf("%d: RSSI%d\n", i, listOfRedes[i].rssi);
    Serial.flush();
  }
  Serial.printf("salio\n");
  Serial.flush();
  qsort (listOfRedes, n, sizeof(red), compare);
  Serial.printf("ordeno\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // ...initialize it
  {
    yield();
    Serial.printf("%d: RSSI:%" PRId32 "\n", listOfRedes[i].id, listOfRedes[i].rssi);
  }
}
```

and this is the output i get

```
0: RSSI-69
1: RSSI-65
2: RSSI-72
3: RSSI-50
4: RSSI-60
5: RSSI-87
6: RSSI-87
7: RSSI-79
8: RSSI-80
9: RSSI-88
10: RSSI-74
11: RSSI-77
12: RSSI-78
13: RSSI-83
14: RSSI-79
15: RSSI-60
16: RSSI-85
17: RSSI-86
18: RSSI-66
19: RSSI-88
20: RSSI-80
21: RSSI-74
22: RSSI-81
23: RSSI-87
salio
ordeno
4: RSSI:-60
1: RSSI:-65
0: RSSI:-69
3: RSSI:-50
18: RSSI:-66
15: RSSI:-60
2: RSSI:-72
10: RSSI:-74
11: RSSI:-77
21: RSSI:-74
19: RSSI:-88
20: RSSI:-80
22: RSSI:-81
23: RSSI:-87
12: RSSI:-78
5: RSSI:-87
6: RSSI:-87
7: RSSI:-79
8: RSSI:-80
9: RSSI:-88
13: RSSI:-83
14: RSSI:-79
16: RSSI:-85
17: RSSI:-86
```

As you can see the sorting is not OK and I don't get why.
Thank you in advance and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Thanks st2000 i did not know how to formatt it

Comment: Don't use `qsort`, use `std::sort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program there is this line of code:

```
  return redA->rssi > redB->rssi ? 1 : (redB->rssi < redA->rssi ? -1 : 0);
```

Which appears to return a 1 if A is greater then B other wise it will return a 0.  This code can not tell the difference between A < B and A == B.  Consider altering this line of code to allow returning 1 for A > B, 0 for A == B and -1 for A < B:

```
  return redA->rssi > redB->rssi ? 1 : (redA->rssi < redB->rssi ? -1 : 0);
```

Comment: can't belive i did that.... like.... for hours..... thank you men, i'm an idiot....

Comment: I didn't see it for a while either.  Glad I could help.